# Indent Boxed List Column

Tags: sharepoint-online, css

Is there any way that I can utilize CSS to indent the column within a embedded boxed list so that the left column is slightly away from the left hand border?

[image]

Any help would be much appreciated!

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use the "Boxed" style in list view, we can add the CSS below into a script editor web part in list view to achieve it.

```
<style type="text/css">
.ms-listviewtable .ms-stylebox .ms-stylelabel{
    padding-left:10px !important;
    width:30% !important;
}
</style>
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much. That did the job. Would there also be a way to make the first column show in box and space the right hand column slightly to the right?

Comment: Adjust the width of the ms-stylelabel.